# Matlab 2016b Ubuntu 16.04 LTS installation problem (dvd2)

Tags: matlab

I cannot find the 2nd matlab dvd (iso on my computer) to ultimate the installation process, even though is mounted. How can solve it?

Matlab Screenshot - Eject DVD1 and insert DVD 2 to continue:

[image]

Comment: Having the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/890751/697460
Worked for me to install R2017a.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue and the mistake was that I didn't copy the hidden `.dvd2` file.

My steps to install:

1. Extract `R2016b_glnxa64_dvd1.iso` to `install-1`
2. Extract `R2016b_glnxa64_dvd2.iso` to `install-2`
3. Copy all files from `install-2` to `install-1` (merging), **including the hidden file `.dvd2`**
4. Call the install script inside of `install-1`

Answer (score 6):

I was facing the same issue and did the following trick and it worked. I first installed Furius ISO Mount from Ubuntu Store. Then I mounted the DVD 1 iso file and started the installation. When the prompt asking for DVD 2 popped up, I unmounted DVD 1 from Furius. Then I renamed the DVD 2 iso identical to DVD 1 and mounted it with Furius. On pressing Ok at the install prompt, the installation resumed and worked perfectly.

Comment: This doesn't work. Furius won't let you unmount the iso because it's obviously busy

Answer (score 1):

1. `sudo mkdir /iso`
2. `mount -o loop R2016b_glnxa64_dvd1.iso /iso`
3. `cd /iso` & ./install start install Matlab R2016b
4. when you recieve the notice *"Eject DVD1 and Insert DVD2"*, follows now
5. `umount /iso`, maybe you will get the *"device busy"* notice, you can solve the problem by http://desert.blog.51cto.com/779694/172862
6. then, we execute  `mount -o loop R2016b_glnxa64_dvd2.iso /iso`
7. Click the *"Eject DVD1 and Insert DVD2"* OK button, the installation will be continue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and in my case the reason was, that both virtual disks were automatically mounted with different drive letters. I modified the drive letter of the second DVD to be identical to the first one, and the installation automatically continued.

Answer (score 0):

Extract iso files, and run installation from dvd1 directory:

```
sudo R2017a_glnxa64_dvd1/install
```

When you see the notice ("Eject DVD 1 and Insert DVD 2"),

```
rm -rf R2017a_glnxa64_dvd1/
mv R2017a_glnxa64_dvd2/ R2017a_glnxa64_dvd1/
```

Then, click OK. Installation will be continue.